# How to force simplification and avoid interpolation in simple SASS calculation?

Tags: variables, sass, interpretation

From [SASS docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/calculations):

> You can also use interpolation in a calculation. However, if you do,
> **nothing in the parentheses that surround that interpolation will be
> simplified or type-checked**, so it’s easy to end up with extra verbose
> or even invalid CSS. Rather than writing calc(10px + #{$var}), **just
> write calc(10px + $var)**!

But when I try to compile that

```scss
$var: 10px;

span {
    top: calc(10px + $var); // without interpretation
    bottom: calc(10px + #{$var}); // with interpretation
}
```

I get this:

```css
span {
  top: calc(10px + $var); // obviously wrong
  bottom: calc(10px + 10px);
}
```

If I understand docs correctly, `top` should have assigned value `20px`. Without interpretation, `calc` should be called as internal SASS function and return value. Why it didn't happen? How do I calculate without interpretation?

Comment: Calc doesnt return a value in your css.  However, in your rendering of the calc function on the page, it renders out to the value you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out myself. There are two things:

1. the example in documentation is wrong, you shouldn't write `calc(10px + $var)` but simply `10px + $var`;
2. it must happen as an assigment to SASS variable and NOT as as assingment to CSS attribute.

So this is how it should be written in SASS:

```scss
$var: 10px;
$my_calc: 10px + $var;

span {
    up: #{$my_calc};
    top: calc(10px + $var);
    bottom: calc(10px + #{$var});
}
```

It will properly compile to:

```css
span {
  up: 20px;
  top: calc(10px + $var);
  bottom: calc(10px + 10px);
}
```

Regarding values of `top` and `bottom`: they are correct. SASS treats `calc(10px + $var)` as raw string and simply copies it and treats `calc(10px + #{$var});` as string with interpolated value which it interpolates and then writes to the resulting CSS.

So everything is OK but the SASS docs are misleading.